# UItableview and searchbar with customcell in xib

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am new to Iphone App Development. I have an requirement to develop a `UITableview` with a  `UISearchbar`. I have to display a `json` array in a `tableView` with default a `image` and two `buttons` and two `labels`. The two buttons functionality are + and - one label is using to display the button action and one label to display number the `json` array name.

Exactly, what I need to display... button click count in label for a particular cell and display same count when i search in search bar for same item.

can anyone help me. Please....

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code i tried..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListOfProductsCell";

    ListOfProductsCell *cell = (ListOfProductsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
            NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListOfProductsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        productItemDit=[productListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *offerStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[[productItemDit objectForKey:@"offer"] floatValue]];
        NSString *fullCostStr=[[currencyCodeStr stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:offerStr];
        NSLog(@"%@",fullCostStr);
        cell.itemCostLbl.text=fullCostStr;

        cell.itemStepper.tag=166;
        cell.itemAddedLbl.tag=122;

        itemCount=stepperValueArry.count;
        cell.itemAddedLbl =(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:122];
        cell.itemAddedLbl.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",itemCount];

    }

    cell.itemImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profp.jpg"];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView) {
        searchProductItemDit=[searchProductListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"searchdit:%@",searchProductItemDit);
        cell.itemNameLbl.text= [searchProductItemDit objectForKey:@"name"];
        self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView.separatorColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    } else {
        productItemDit=[productListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"dit:%@",productItemDit);
        cell.itemNameLbl.text=[productItemDit objectForKey:@"name"];

    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: I tried by gooling. But i can not find any answer for this type requirement.

Comment: I am trying this since two weeks

Comment: you got to store those values in a `NSDictionary` with `indexpath` as key and in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method check the dictionary with the specific indexpath whether it is nil , if not load the value from there ..

Comment: Add buttons and labels in "cellForRowAtIndexpath" method of the UITableView. You can refer the links as Anil has given for the searchbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the data from json in dataSource1 array and implement the search bar like below code.
And google for:- Json Parsing, read documents for UITableView and SearchBar to custom the below code

**In ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{

UITableView *myTableView;
NSMutableArray *dataSource1; //will be storing all the data
NSMutableArray *tableData;//will be storing data that will be displayed in table
NSMutableArray *searchedData;//will be storing data matching with the search string
UISearchBar *sBar;//search bar
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *dataSource1;
```

**In ViewController.m**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        sBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
        sBar.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:sBar];

        myTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 41, 320, 400)];
        myTableView.delegate = self;
        myTableView.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:myTableView];

        //initialize the two arrays; dataSource will be initialized and populated by appDelegate
        searchedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        dataSource1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"vivk"];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"Balveer"];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"Balveer"];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"dharmender"];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"aaaaa"];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"aabb"];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"bbbb"];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"ba"];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"ankit"];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"cccc"];
        [dataSource1 addObject:@"ddddd"];


        [tableData addObjectsFromArray:dataSource1];//on launch it should display all the records
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        //NSLog(@"contacts error in num of row");
        return [tableData count];
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    #pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate
    - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    {
        // only show the status bar's cancel button while in edit mode
        sBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
        sBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        // flush the previous search content
        [tableData removeAllObjects];
    }
    - (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    {
        sBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    }

    - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
    {
        [tableData removeAllObjects];// remove all data that belongs to previous search
        if([searchText isEqualToString:@""]||searchText==nil){
            [myTableView reloadData];
            return;
        }
        NSInteger counter = 0;
        for(NSString *name in dataSource1)
        {
            NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(r.location != NSNotFound)
                [tableData addObject:name];
            counter++;
        }
        [myTableView reloadData];
    }
    - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    {
        // if a valid search was entered but the user wanted to cancel, bring back the main list content
        [tableData removeAllObjects];
        [tableData addObjectsFromArray:dataSource1];
        @try{
            [myTableView reloadData];
        }
        @catch(NSException *e){
        }
        [sBar resignFirstResponder];
        sBar.text = @"";
    }
    // called when Search (in our case "Done") button pressed
    - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    {
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Start off by parsing your JSON and store the required values into an array. Try using AFNetworking.

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Create a custom cell as per your requirement and work with that.

[Custom Cell](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

After that, create a `UITableView` with the above custom cell and the array you received after parsing the JSON.

Implement a Search bar with the help of the following:

[Search Bar](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/)

Comment: Thanks,I tried with that links. I am getting Output Correctly.

Comment: I have one problem, When i scroll the table view the value of button action label is disappearing and i am not getting same value for that item when i search in searchbar.

Comment: try defining the required values inside if (cell == nil) might solve your problem

Comment: i done what you said. But value of button action is not displaying for same cell. When i click button in one cell its displaying value in same cell and also displaying other cells as randomly.

Comment: When you're scrolling, the UITableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. That's where the issue is occuring. Look into that method and see if something can be altered.

Comment: i tried by debug the code. Issue is when i scroll the tableview the new cells is creating again.